# Random Number generation

Tags: random

What should be the approach to generate 10 unique numbers that should not match among a group of 10 people's generated answer ?

Comment: No alphabets or special characters are allowed, only with 0-9 and sum of 10 random number should be minimum.

Comment: A GUID is just a number. You don't _have_ to display it in hexadecimal with separating dashes.

Comment: @cha0site: You should list your guid comment as an answer.

Comment: Surely the condition "sum of 10 random number should be minimum" makes the choice not random

Answer (score 3):

This one has a nice solution. I'm assuming you have to give numbers 1-10 to 10 different people in a random way (but the principle also works if you have 10 (or more) different, non-consecutive numbers).

- Arrange the numbers in an array.
- Use a shuffling algorithm to shuffle the elements in the array.

  - (Shuffling algorithms : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
- Read the first 10 values from the array, assigning them to each of the ten people.

Answer (score 2):

You could use OS facilities to generate a GUID (globally unique identifier).

A GUID is a 32-digit hexadecimal that looks like this: `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` (shamelessly stolen from the [GUID wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)). That makes it a 128 bit number. Now, it has all those annoying characters in the way, but there's nothing stopping you from removing the extraneous character and converting from hex and treating it as a plain number.

For practical reasons, you'll want to note that a 128-bit number is a bit unwieldy in some languages, such as C99. But you can still use compiler extensions (GCC has `__uint128_t`) or deal with it some other way.